# Strange text highlighting in Firefox

Tags: php, css, firefox

I have a strange issue in Firefox with the following website: http://staffroom.bytewire.co.uk/

If you click on the little down arrow to the right of the logo the text in the div appears like it has been highlighted.

If you click off this then click back onto it the highlighting is gone and it appears as it should.

Firefox is the only browser that this occurs in, can anyone shed any light as to why? and how to stop it?

Thanks

Elliot

Comment: Can you post the CSS/PHP code for the relevant div?

Comment: Interestingly when you put `jQuery("#switcher-panel").show();` into the web console immediately after page load, it doesn't happen.

Comment: Can you change that event to a hover rather than a click temporarily and see if the problem still happens?

Comment: ...or maybe try adding `jQuery(this).blur();` before the `jQuery("#switcher-panel").show();` line in the click handler

Comment: @BillyMoat I have changed it to a hover, which you see on the site, and it no longer highlights the text. Now we need a solution for the clicking of the button!

Comment: @Elliot Reeve - Could you not possibly just leave it as a hover? But obviously have the menu hide itself when you hover off of it?

Comment: @BillyMoat - Not sure I want to keep it as a hover going forward

Comment: Seems to be working in Firefox now.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to   **body.clearbooks #header-content #main-switcher**

```
outline-style:none;
```

This will work.

Comment: Thanks Aditya, I have added this but it dosen't seem to have solved the issue.

Comment: Elliot, I just tested this on FF on Mac and I don't see the selected text anymore. I will try another solution for this and update.

Comment: Have you now changed the menu to open on hover instead of click ?

Comment: I changed it to hover to see if it resolved the problem, which it did, but I don't want to keep it as a hover going forward.

Comment: @ElliotReeve Hi Elliot, did you find a solution to your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the structure of the elements a bit and this seems to have, randomly, resolved the issue!

Thanks for the help.